# What is the difference between BAT0 and ADP0 on the linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, devices, power-management, acpi, battery

Well I'm trying to identify a device in my program so I can classify and get the power status of a device. The thing is that I'm getting different values on the same OS but using different machines.

I know I can use:

```
upower
demidecode
acpi
```

But if for some reason is not available I want to have another option!

What is the difference between them? Note that one of the laptops doesn't have a battery connected.

With battery: BAT0

Without battery: ADP0

The path used: /sys/class/power_supply/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are [acpi](http://www.acpi.info/) names (4 character, upper case...) BAT0 is the first battery, the second if you had one would be BAT1. ADP0 is the first ac-ADaPter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just to clarify: What type of device has 2 batteries? Is the adapter only shown on a portable device or battery enable device? My desktop doesn't show anything!! No battery (obviously) nor an adapter on any program or path mentioned above

Comment: Some laptops have two batteries, although they are rare. What devices there are depends on the writer of the acpi tables, which is almost always the BIOS (but google "patch acpi table"). With USB-C we might start seeing devices with multiple ac adapters.

Comment: Good to know! Perfect