# Understanding power_supply files

Tags: linux, arch-linux, power-management, battery

It is a very simple question, but I think that in its simplicity it has aqua output.

the case is I am interested in better understanding the files that are hosted in `/sys/class/power_supply`, and that manage the battery monitoring of the system. In my case I use a laptop with a battery, the directory of which is located in `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0`. On the other hand I have the *ac-ADaPter* interface in `/sys/class/power_supply/AC0`, as I understand from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332859/what-is-the-difference-between-bat0-and-adp0-on-the-linux-kernel).

Inside the battery interface, I find various files:

```
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0$ ls
alarm               model_name
capacity            power
capacity_level      present
charge_full         serial_number
charge_full_design  status
charge_now          subsystem
current_now         technology
cycle_count         type
device              uevent
hwmon2              voltage_min_design
manufacturer        voltage_now
```

I understand that `capacity` reference to the current battery percentage. i also understand by context `capacity_level` and `status`:

```
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0$ cat capacity
81

/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0$ cat capacity_level
Normal

/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0$ cat status
Discharging
```

however, I don't understand other files like `charge_full`, `charge_full_design`, `charge_now`, `current_now` or `cycle_count`:

```
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0$ cat charge_full
900000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0$ cat charge_full_design
4100000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0$ cat charge_now
630000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0$ cat current_now
1191000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0$ cat cycle_count
0
```

In the `uevent` class you can review each previous variable, with some more detail:

```
POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=BAT0
POWER_SUPPLY_TYPE=Battery
POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Discharging
POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-ion
POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=0
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=11400000
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=11759000
POWER_SUPPLY_CURRENT_NOW=1089000
POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL_DESIGN=4100000
POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL=900000
POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_NOW=675000
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY=75
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY_LEVEL=Normal
POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=standard
POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=OEM
POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER=00001
```

Understanding clearly that the percentage of battery capacity comes from calculation of `POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_NOW` (`/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_now`) on `POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL` (`/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full`): 100*675000/900000=75.

But how can you understand these values? where does `POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_NOW` come from? does the voltage of the above values interfere in anything?

Comment: This is probably a bit of a research project but you might find help here https://www.acpica.org/documentation  There is a lot of relevant documentation but I’m not sure if it contains exactly what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to see how the Linux power-supply device class is defined in [include/linux/power_supply.h](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/include/linux/power_supply.h?h=v6.0.11) in Linux kernel source code. The values in the data structures described there are presented as-is in `/sys/class/power_supply/*`:

```
/*
 * All voltages, currents, charges, energies, time and temperatures in uV,
 * µA, µAh, µWh, seconds and tenths of degree Celsius unless otherwise
 * stated. It's driver's job to convert its raw values to units in which
 * this class operates.
 */

/*
 * For systems where the charger determines the maximum battery capacity
 * the min and max fields should be used to present these values to user
 * space. Unused/unknown fields will not appear in sysfs.
 */
```

So all the `charge_*` values are in units of microampere-hours, and `current_now` is in microamperes.

```
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=11400000
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=11759000
```

The battery's minimum design voltage (= should never be discharged to below this voltage) is 11400000 microvolts = 11.4 volts.

The current voltage level is 11.759 volts.

```
POWER_SUPPLY_CURRENT_NOW=1089000
```

The battery is right now providing 1.089 amps of current.

```
POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL_DESIGN=4100000
POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL=900000
POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_NOW=675000
```

When it was new, the battery claims to have had a fully-charged capacity of 4.10 amp-hours, but it has since then degraded so the current fully-charged capacity is only 0.9 amp-hours. Currently, it has 0.675 amp-hours of charge left.

So, as a simple estimate, with the current you're taking from the battery right now, you'll have 0.675 Ah / 1.089 A = about 0.62 hours, or about 37 minutes of power left.

The `power_supply.h` file has a lot of other informative comments, that directly describe what the various values mean. You might want to read those comments.

Comment: I don't know if this is the place, for what happens if `POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW` set almost always (when not connected to AC) below `POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN`? (should I create a new question?)

Comment: That together with the large difference between `POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL_DESIGN` and `POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL` suggests to me that the battery is probably almost completely worn out and might fail at any time.